# TJsonSerializer with arrays

Tags: json, delphi

I have a record notably containing the following field :

```
colorMatrix: Array [1 .. 2] of Array [1 .. 5] of TColor;
```

Unfortunately, calling TJsonSerializer's Serialise function does not serialise this field. How do I make it do so ?